# Auto Layout broken on iOS 8.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-autolayout, ios8.1, visual-format-language

I'm working with Auto Layout Visual Format Language and using the following expressions:

- H:|[_tableView]|
- H:|[_actionButton]|
- V:|[_tableView][_actionButton(==buttonHeight)]|

They work fine in 9 and 10, but in iOS 8.1 we noticed that the layout is not working as expected. 
The view is getting the double of dimensions.

- **For iOS 10**
- `<UIWindow: frame = (0 0; 320 568);>`
- `<UIView: frame = (0 0; 320 568);`
- **For iOS 8.1**
- `<UIWindow: frame = (0 0; 320 568);>`
- `<UIView: frame = (0 0; 640 1136);>`

The testing code im using:

- ViewController - http://pastebin.com/PjQpKJBD
- AppDelegate.m - http://pastebin.com/4iri9Yp5

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug appears to be caused in your app delegate, by initializing the window and calling `makeKeyAndVisible` before it has a frame. Replace this line:

```
self.window = [UIWindow new];
```

With an explicit frame on initialization:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

...and remove the redundant line setting the window's frame afterwards.
Alternatively you could move the call to `makeKeyAndVisible` after the setting the window's frame, ie:

```
if (initViewController)
{
    self.window = [UIWindow new];
    self.window.rootViewController = initViewController;
    self.window.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Either way should work.